# How to create a new table from a join

Tags: sql, join

I need to put the following join into a SQL table:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Disbursements_Master_Vendor_Tbl]
    LEFT JOIN [Disbursements_Bravo_Vendor_Master_Tbl]
        ON [Disbursements_Master_Vendor_Tbl].Vendor = [Disbursements_Bravo_Vendor_Master_Tbl].Username
WHERE [Disbursements_Master_Vendor_Tbl].Vendor IS NULL OR [Disbursements_Bravo_Vendor_Master_Tbl].Username IS NULL
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Are you asking how to insert the results of that SQL query in to a table?

Comment: What DBMS are you using Brian? MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have defined the table with your fields you intend to insert the data into using the create table statement.

```
INSERT INTO Table_Name (column value1, column value2, etc..)

SELECT * FROM [Disbursements_Master_Vendor_Tbl] LEFT JOIN
Disbursements_Bravo_Vendor_Master_Tbl] ON
[Disbursements_Master_Vendor_Tbl].Vendor
[Disbursements_Bravo_Vendor_Master_Tbl].Username WHERE
[Disbursements_Master_Vendor_Tbl].Vendor IS NULL OR
[Disbursements_Bravo_Vendor_Master_Tbl].Username IS NULL
```

OR:

Using the SELECT INTO statement (only when the table hasn't been created):

```
SELECT * INTO TableName 
FROM [Disbursements_Master_Vendor_Tbl] LEFT JOIN
Disbursements_Bravo_Vendor_Master_Tbl] ON
[Disbursements_Master_Vendor_Tbl].Vendor
[Disbursements_Bravo_Vendor_Master_Tbl].Username WHERE
[Disbursements_Master_Vendor_Tbl].Vendor IS NULL OR
[Disbursements_Bravo_Vendor_Master_Tbl].Username IS NULL
```

Comment: Perhaps you could include a `SELECT INTO` example for Brian? Although Brian doesn't specify what DBMS he is using.

Comment: Done! Thanks for the suggestion, @JonathonOgden!